# How to get online images list in flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, httpserver

Does flex allow to fetch contents from server?

Ex: The server is `http://www.sample.com/images/`, and the contents like `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`, `img3.jpg`, etc...

How to get those images in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a file on the server that describes the data in that directory. Most easily an XML file with a list of the directory contents. Then you load up that known file, parse out the results, then load each of the images within it. 
Alternatively, and not recommended, if the data does follow the pattern such that it is sequentially numbered like that, you could try to load images, starting at 1, looping until you get a 404. Not as elegant, but would work.